# Не задается программно fragment в FragmentContainerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Я использовал код документации гугл:

activity_main.xml:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

MainActivity.kt:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add<MapFragment>(R.id.main_container)
            }
        }
    }
```

В итоге белый экран, но если добавить в xml вместо пропуска `android:name="com.example.app.MapFragment"`, который задает начальный фрагмент, то он отображается на экране и без программного добавления, а необходимо как раз это сделать программно.
Я пробовал различные варианты из гугла, ничего не получалось. Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0):

В xml нужно всегда указывать NavHostFragment

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
app:defaultNavHost="true"
```

Чтобы добавить начальный фрагмент в коде нужно:

```
val navGraph = findNavController(R.id.main_container).navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.your_app_navigation)  
navGraph.startDestination = R.id.yourFragment
findNavController(R.id.main_container).graph = navGraph
```

Пример с таким подходом можно посмотреть [тут](https://github.com/WiMank/Playlist-Export-For-Spotify/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/wimank/pbfs/ui/activity/MainActivity.kt)